# Beep function in VB6. What "beeps"?

Tags: vb6, hardware

VB6 has a Beep function. I am curious to know what exactly beeps when this function is called. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that's the motherboard beeper.

Comment: Apparently this relic got carried forward to .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz27k38z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be more accurate VB6 has a Beep *subroutine*, not a function.

This isn't related to the Kernel32 Beep entrypoint at all, and works just as well in Vista as in Windows 7, XP, or Windows 95.

It plays the "Default Beep" sound from the user's Windows sound scheme.  If the system has no sound card it should beep via the motherboard speaker the same way this sound is played for anything else in Windows that invokes it.

It is just a generic audible alert.  It probably was only included for use by old, old MS Basic programs being ported forward into VB.

Comment: I presume it uses the [`MessageBeep(MB_OK)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 2):

If the motherboard has a speaker built-in (either a small tweeter speaker in ancient motherboards or an even smaller beep speaker in not-so-ancient motherboards), then that's what beeps.  In Windows Vista the Beep function was no longer supported, however In Windows 7 the Beep function was resurrected and is routed through the computer's sound device.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -2):

To use the motherboard built-in speaker and bypass the computer's sound device whether installed or not, use this (only tested on XP)..

Declare Function SysBeep& Lib "kernel32" Alias "Beep" (ByVal Freq As Long, ByVal Duration As Long)

This should be self-explanatory, but if not, seed help on "Declare".